# CodeIgniter unable to update database

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I have a problem regarding the user login in my web application. What I'm trying to do is to update a particular user's `last_online_at` value with the current date and time before he / she will be landed to the main page. However, it did not update as I expect it to do so.

Here is my code:

```
...

 if($result != FALSE){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('user_type');
    $this->db->where("id ='" . $result[0]->user_type_id . "'");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $session_data = array('first_name' => $result[0]->first_name,
                          'last_name' => $result[0]->last_name,
                          'username' => $result[0]->username,
                          'email' => $result[0]->email,
                          'id' => $result[0]->user_id,
                          'created_at' => date_parse($result[0]->created_at),
                          'recent_searches' => array(),
                          'food_tray' => array('Sample', 'Test', 'Qwerty'),
                          'logged_in' => TRUE,
                          'user_type' => $query->row()->name,
                          'user_type_id' => $result[0]->user_type_id,
                          'user_privileges' => array());

    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

    // LINE OF CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR UPDATING `last_online_at` VALUE //

    $data = array('last_online_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $this->db->update('user', $data, 'id =' . $session_data['id']);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if($session_data['user_type'] == 'Customer'){
        // REDIRECT TO USER PAGE
        redirect(base_url() . "index.php/main");
    }else if($session_data['user_type'] == 'Aggregator' ||
             $session_data['user_type'] == 'Restaurant Owner' ||
             $session_data['user_type'] == 'System Admin'){
        // REDIRECT TO ADMIN DASHBOARD
        redirect(base_url() . "index.php/admin?page_view=admin_dash");
    }               
}
```

As you can see from the given code snippet, I used the variable `$session_data['id']` to substitute as argument value to the where clause in the update query, and that's the one that doesn't work. But when I replace it to a static value, for example, 1, it will work smoothly and update record based on the given static value

Am I doing something wrong with this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So what does a var_dump of $session_data look like?  Use var_dump($session_data); Then you can see if id is being set correctly or not.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me!  I just observed that when I var_dumped the session_data, it turned out that the value for id is `NULL` and already replaced it with correct array index

Comment: Excellent :) It's always a good thing to observe your variables to validate that they are doing what you think they should be doing...

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to ensure that `$session_data['id']` is has the correct value in it.

So before it tries to use print to what exactly contain by `$session_data`

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($session_data);
echo "</pre>";
```

I also suggest you use CodeIgniter log.

```
log_message('debug', 'Your Session Data: '.print_r($session_data, TRUE));
log_message('debug', 'You can see last executed query also: '.print_r($this->db->last_query(), TRUE));
```

Before using this please enable the log form config.

This technique helps you to get what happens in your code.

And for update, the last login date try this:

```
$data = array('last_online_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$this->db->where('id', $session_data['id']);
$this->db->update('user', $data);
```